# Create and populate a test database to run Cucumber tests on

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I want to test my Ruby-on-Rails website that uses PostgreSQL database with Cucumber.

I also have the FactoryGirl gem installed, so I can create factories.

I understand that the typical way to create data for the test database would be to write Gherkin tables and put them in the background block of a cucumber file. But I already have a Ruby script that creates samle data suitable for the test database.

Yet, I am currently lost in Cucumber’s settings. Could you please advise how to make Cucumber run my Ruby script populating the test database before each test and how to clean the test database after each test. Apparently, my google-fu is inadequate for this task.

Comment: Hey, I think https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Fixtures this could be helpful to you. I do wanted to ask `the typical way to create data for the test database would be to write Gherkin tables and put them in the background block of a cucumber file`.  Can you suggest me some link for this? To be precise, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29426693/how-to-create-users-database-in-cucumberjs this is my query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just:

1. add the cucumber rule like `I have 4 clock in the pocket` to **features/clock.feature** (for example).
2. implement the rule in the **features/step_definition/clock_steps.rb** (for example) to create defined amount Clock models, and single Pocket model. and associate them:

   ```
   When /I have (\d+) clock in the pocket/ do |amount|
      pocket = FactoryGirl.create :pocket
      amount.times { FactoryGirl.create :clock, pocket: pocket }
   end
   ```

So, you then will get some data populated.

If you want predefine the step for most scenarios you can either:

- Create a larger step (for example) called `I have basic clock setup`, then define it as an above one, but add another required steps into it.

or

- Use step recursion (this is **non-recommended** way) as follows:

  ```
  When /I have basic clock setup/ do |amount|
     step 'I have 4 clock in the pocket'
  end
  ```

Comment: But what if I _always_ have 4 clock in the pocket? Across all features and all scenarios. I need these 4 clocks for my website to function at all. Where do I put the code in this case?

Comment: I added an answer that I eventually used. I am sure that your suggestion is the most standard and straightforward way of how this task should be approached, but for some obscure reason my test database refused to cooperate when I translated my setup script into the sequence of steps in a Given block.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a `Before do` block in the .rb file with Cucumber tests:

```
Before do
  <code to populate the test database here>
end

Given /first condition/
  do some stuff
end

...and so on
```

Comment: What do you mean "my db refused to cooperate"?

Comment: To set up the test database, I had to go through a sequence of steps: create a user, create a website model associated with this user, create another user, create a website model associated with that second user. The second website model failed to save in the database returning the error `ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved: ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved`. I must have made some mistake somewhere, but for the life of me I couldn’t see where.

Comment: It seems that some validation weren't passes for second web site, may be it is name etc